# Is it possible to add 1 month to a number of jquery datepickers?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to add 1 month to a number of datepickers, the values have already been set are are in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

```
$(".monthpicker").each(function() {    
    var d = $(this).val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate',d);
});
```

I have tried

```
$(this).datepicker('setDate',d +1m);
```

but it does nothing. Is it possible to add 1 month to all the values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Add months to Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031249/jquery-add-months-to-datepicker)

Comment: No, I am reading from existing datepicker fields

Comment: "*it does nothing*" - are you sure?  Did you check the console and see "Invalid or unexpected token"?  If not, maybe your code isn't getting called (so do you have any elements with class `monthpicker` when the code runs?)  A [mcve] might help.

Comment: no exceptions in the console

Comment: The key parts of that answer is that you create a date object and add the months to that date object. Where you get the date in the first place `var d = new Date();` vs `var d = new Date($(this).val());` vs `var d = $(this).datepicker("getdate")` isn't relevant, so the answer still applies even if you're getting it from "existing datepicker fields"

Comment: Then there's something else wrong as `d+1m` is not valid javascript and gives an error.

Comment: conssole.log(d); sends the current values to the console. So the code is being called